# Handle a token one of two ways depending on context

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

Is it possible to handle the same lexical token differently depending on context? The docs says there are [`Lexical Modes`](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#mode-pushmode-popmode-and-more) as a way to handle this, and was wondering if that approach could be used to handle this.

Here is an example. Given the following SQL statement:

```
select 1.2, 1.2e, .2, 1.e, tbl, tbl.select
```

Notice that the `SELECT` token at the beginning is a reserved keyword, but when the reserved token is preceded by a `.` it is part of a "path expression" and so is not a reserved keyword. What I want to do is -- ignoring numbers -- I want the first `select` to be captured as the `select` token and the second `select` to be captured as an `identifier`. Is this possible? Here is an example in antlr:

```
grammar DBParser;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }

statement:select_statement EOF;

select_statement
    : SELECT expr (COMMA expr)*
    ;

expr
    : NUMBER
    | IDENTIFIER
    ;


COMMA: ',';

// 1. Pick up numbers first (simplified number format for question)
NUMBER: [0-9]* '.' [0-9]* 'e'?;

// 2. Reserved Keyword section
SELECT: 'SELECT';

// 3. And if it's not a reserved keyword, pick it up as an identifier
IDENTIFIER: [A-Z_] [A-Z_0-9]*;


WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

And here is the parse tree, where everything is ok until the `select` after the dot. Is there a rule I can set so that I can properly parse the above at the lexing stage?

---

**Update**: A more complex example might be something like:

```
select ([{'select': 1}])[0].select;
```

Where dot access may be (and often is) after a parenthesized expression, array access, function call, etc.

[image]

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't do this, as long as you can definitely identify the `.` which is used to mark a table selector. SQL has lots of odd corners so you'll have to do your own investigation about whether the `.` token always puts you into no-keyword mode. (That's not the same as the `.` character. `.` in 2.3 is not a token, and it would be the `,` token action which would need to switch modes.) You'll also have to decide whether that solution is cleaner than the one discussed earlier, where you do the work in the parser.

Comment: After you do all that investigation and try it out, you might want to answer you own question with the results.

Comment: @rici yea I haven't been able to figure out a way yet, but with respect to the dot in the numbers (or other things not mentioned in the question, such as a string, comment, etc.) that would be consumed by the number token (if it matches a proper number).

Comment: Yes, precisely. So as long as the token `.` is never followed by a keyword, you can change the lexical mode in the `.` handler, and restore it in every non-skipped handler in the special mode (of which there are not very many, since the special mode doesn't recognise keywords).

Comment: @rici yea I think that approach would work. Do you know how to do that in antlr, or haven't done that before in it?

Comment: Read the "Lexer Commands" section in the link you pasted. (That's all I know. Not really an antlr user).

Comment: @rici I think I posted a possible approach, but it is even worse than the original approach. The lexer rules are pretty limited, outside of maybe matching a string or basic tag.

Comment: As far as I know, it is impossible to know the parse context in the lexer. The [call to the lexer](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/bc8df83d7b9dd75f9cb6b711b090d639aaf4cb74/runtime/CSharp/src/Atn/ParserATNSimulator.cs#L433) in AdaptivePredict() does not pass a state, and there's nothing in the parser to know [what state AdaptivePredict() is working on](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/bc8df83d7b9dd75f9cb6b711b090d639aaf4cb74/runtime/CSharp/src/Atn/ParserATNSimulator.cs#L437). The state is encoded in a stack variable. The usual way to handle something like this is through Antlr modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Mike for the suggestion on how to push the special mode's token back into the normal `IDENTIFIER` token. Here is a working example with both quoted and normal identifiers:

```
parser grammar DBParser;
options { tokenVocab = DBLexer;}
root
   : select_statement EOF
   ;
select_statement
    : SELECT expr (COMMA expr)*
    ;
expr
    : expr '.' IDENTIFIER
    | NUMBER
    | IDENTIFIER
    ;
```

```
lexer grammar DBLexer;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }

// Default mode
DOT : '.' -> mode(PATH_MODE) ;
COMMA: ',';
NUMBER: [0-9]* '.' [0-9]* 'e'?;
SELECT: 'SELECT';
IDENTIFIER: [A-Z_] [A-Z_0-9]* | BQuoteQuoteEscape ;
WS : [ \r\t\n] -> skip ;
fragment BQuoteQuoteEscape: '`' ~[`]*('``' ~[`]*)* '`';

// Special dot-identifier mode only
mode PATH_MODE;
Identifier: [ \r\t\n]* ([a-z_][a-z0-9_]+ | BQuoteQuoteEscape) -> type(IDENTIFIER), mode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

And with input:

```
select 1.2, 1.2e, .2, 1.e, tbl, tbl. select.select.asdf . `select`, `select`.select
```

We get:

[image]

Comment: FYI... You can use the `type()` action to override the token type generated by a lexer rule (makes the parser rules simpler.  Just add `-> type(IDENTIFIER)` to the `IDENTIFIER_2` rule and it'll generate an `IDENTIFIER` token and the parser will never see an `IDENTIFIER_2` token.

Comment: @MikeCargal nice! Just updated my answer and that works great!

Answer (score 1):

The lexer runs independently of the parser, and parser context cannot influence the lexer (tokenization).

Taking into account your additional example you could do something like the following (a common way of handling anywhere keywords may be allowed but not treated as keywords). (NOTE: I had to add a `STRING` rule so that the `select` inside the string wouldn't be recognized as a `SELECT` token, but that seems a reasonable assumption.  It also doesn't parse your example due to the lack of rule for '(' '[' and ':', etc. but I did not take the liberty of attempting to substitute them.

```
grammar DBParser;
options { caseInsensitive=true; }

statement:select_statement EOF;

select_statement
    : SELECT expr (COMMA expr)*
    ;

expr
    : NUMBER
    | IDENTIFIER
    | STRING
    | expr '.' (IDENTIFIER | keyword)
    ;

keyword
    : SELECT
//  | ...
    ;


COMMA: ',';

// 1. Pick up numbers first (simplified number format for question)
NUMBER: [0-9]* '.' [0-9]* 'e'?;

// 2. Reserved Keyword section
SELECT: 'SELECT';

// 3. And if it's not a reserved keyword, pick it up as an identifier
IDENTIFIER: [A-Z_] [A-Z_0-9]*;

STRING: '\'' ~[']* '\'';

WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Also note that the `skip` on whitespace allows for `select ([{'select': 1}])[0] . select;` to also be valid.  Whether or not that is correct I don't really know, but I suspect it would be desirable in order to break statements across multiple lines.

Just my humble opinion, but I think you'll find that trying to switch lexical modes based on the '.' will not prove productive.

Comment: I just added another example, as the 'dot-access' can often be outside of the context of an identifier, for example accessing a literal or after an array access, etc.

Comment: what about this part though, where it says you can "change modes" in the Lexer? https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#mode-pushmode-popmode-and-more

Comment: I just added an answer here as well. Using lexer modes is pretty inadequate to solve the above problem imo.